# Python TKinter for real time GUIs

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have written a monitoring program for the control system at our plant. It is basically a GUI which lets the operator see the current status of the lock of the closed loop system and aware the operator in case the lock/loop breaks.

Now, the operation is heavily dependent on the responses of the GUI. My seniors told me that they prefer just the console prints instead of using TKinter based GUI as TKinter has lags while working in real time.

Can anyone please comment on this aspect?
Can this lag be checked and corrected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tkinter lag would likely be measured in tens or maybe hundreds of milliseconds, but there is definitely a tiny lag. Do you really need sub-second response times?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if your program is simply accessing data and not interacting with the data, then a GUI seems to be a bit of overkill. GUI's are guided user interfaces, as you know, and are made for guiding a user through an interface. If the interface is just a status, as you indicated, then I see nothing wrong with a console program.

If, however, your program also interacts with data in a way that would be difficult without a GUI, then the GUI is likely the right choice.

Have you considered a GUI in another programming language? Python is known to be a bit slow, even in console. In my experience, C++ is faster in terms of viewing data. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for response.
The situation goes like this. It is a kind of status read and issue the protection commands.
GUI is just showing status of various entities in the control system. Indicating alarms, use of different colors to indicate different conditions. It is basically meant for operator people who are not much aware of terminologies, and can help us by reporting emergency situations.

Rest, I have a client software that is written in C which itself is a quite big and complex program, but using python I found GUI implementation quite simple and concise for this particular application.

Comment: Python and Tkinter should be a good GUI if visuals are simple to be shown.  But the way you implement it should strongly drive your performances. If you ca set your visual indicators then quickly identify objects you have to play with. You ca see evolutions without human timing lag effect.

Answer (score 0):

## Python / tkinter in general

In a `tkinter` program, your code falls in one of four categories;

1. Initialization code that runs before the `mainloop` is started.
2. Callbacks that are run from within the `mainloop`.
3. Code running in other threads.
4. Code running in different processes.

In the first case, the time the code takes only influences the startup time, which for a long-running program is probably not all that relevant.

Concerning the second case, well-written callbacks should not take that long to run. In the order of tens of milliseconds, maybe up to 100 ms. If they take longer, they will render the GUI unresponsive. So unless you notice a sluggish GUI (without threads; see below) this should not be a problem.

One pitfall here are `after` callbacks, that is functions that will be scheduled to run after a certain time. If you launch them *too often*, this will also starve the GUI of time.

Another possible problem *might* be the manipulation of a `Canvas` with lots and lots of items in it.

As of Python 3.x, `tkinter` is thread-safe to the best of my understanding. However, in the reference implementation of Python, *only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode*. So doing heavy calculations in a second thread would slow down the GUI.

If you GUI uses `multiprocessing` to run calculations in another process, that should not influence the speed of your GUI much, unless you do things wrong when communicating with that other process.

## Your monitoring program

What is too slow depends on the situation. In general  Python is not considered a language suitable for *hard* [real-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Criteria_for_real-time_computing) programs. To do hard real-time one also needs a suitable operating system.

So the question then becomes what is the acceptable lag in your system specification? Without knowing that it is impossible to precisely answer your question.

It seems that your GUI is just displaying some system status. That should not cause too much of a load, *provided that you don't read/check the data too often*. As described in the callbacks paragraph above it is possible to starve your GUI of CPU cycles with callbacks that run too often. From what you've written, I gather that the GUI's task is just to inform the human operator.
That leads me to believe that the task is not hugely time  critical; a system that requires millisecond intervention time should not rely on a human operator.

So based on your information I would say that a competently written GUI should probably not be too slow.